# Docker Compose identify cluster

Tags: docker-compose

When launching docker-compose, it seems that the directory path is used to identify the cluster.

If I want to shutdown a cluster, I must `cd` to where it was started and run `docker-compose down`.

Can I provide a name / identifier to `docker-compose up` that I can also pass to `docker-compose down` in order to start it / stop it from any working directory?